# How can I hide icon under row in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I hide the icon under the white background of the line?

From below is my implementation of the method:

```
 @Override
        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
            Paint p = new Paint();
            Bitmap icon;
            if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){

                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                float width = height / 3;

                if(dX > 0){
                    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#125688"));
                    RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft(), (float) itemView.getTop(), dX,(float) itemView.getBottom());
                    c.drawRect(background,p);
                    icon = drawableToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_delete_black));
                    RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft() + width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getLeft()+ 2*width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                    c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
                }
            }

            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNtzx.png)

Comment: Try including the sample image within your post so we can easily see what the desired behavior is without going to another site.

Answer (score 0):

View.Visibility=viewstates.Invisible
Not sure if it will help u solve the problem.